# SQL - JOINING to table with a key that requires parsing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-normalization

I am new to SQL Server. I was trying to do query on a table which contains user list with location filter (multiple location). Below is the table.

User data table:

```
firstname   lastname    LocFilter
-----------------------------------------------------------
Riswan      Parambath   Lo_ID=251
Reda        Dridi       Lo_ID=733 or Lo_ID=758 or Lo_ID=783
```

Location table:

```
LocID   LocationName
-----------------------
251     Qatar
733     Turkmenistan
758     Brunei
773     Iraq North
783     Iraq South
```

Now I am trying to query the table using inner join to get the country name using below code

```
SELECT 
    SecUsers.firstname, 
    Location.LocationName
FROM 
    SecUsers
INNER JOIN 
    Location on SecUsers.LocFilter = Location.LocID
```

But I am getting the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Lo_ID=962' to data type int.

It will be great if someone can help to fix this issue.

Comment: add the structure of the tables in the question

Comment: Does `LocFilter` really contain the value `Lo_ID=733 or Lo_ID=758 or Lo_ID=783`?  Or are there three records for Reda Dridi?

Comment: Is the value in your table `[User]` for the column `locFilter` really `'Lo_ID=733 or Lo_ID=758 or Lo_ID=783'`. The problem is quite clear here, that's a string, it's not a integer.

Comment: you need to learn about normalisation, you shouldn't store multiple values in a column like that otherwise you'll face issues like the one you are facing, i.e. it's very difficult to perform direct joins as you've put multiple values together in a single column with a different data type and no relationship between the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having three rules in single cell violates normal form.  From your thread, I could see this as table that already exists.  So, I am providing following solution that can solve your exception.  But, you have to change your table design for scalable solution.

```
select Distinct
    Users.firstname, 
    Location.LocationName
from 
    SecUsers
inner join 
    Location on SecUsers.LocFilter like ('%Lo_ID=' + CAST(Location.LocID as VARCHAR(5)) + '%')
```

Comment: Got error message 

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%Lo_ID=' to data type int.

Comment: select Distinct
        Users.firstname, 
        Location.LocationName
    from 
        SecUsers
    inner join 
        Location on SecUsers.LocFilter like ('%Lo_ID=' + CAST(Location.LocID as varchar(5)) + '%')

Comment: Thanks @Barani. It helped

Comment: Let us hope that all the location id are exactly 3 digits. Otherwise this is likely to return more rows than expected. The performance for this is also terrible

Comment: @Barani some value has more than 3  values. But I think it should be okay for now as there are no much data. Really appreciated your support.

Comment: Riswan - This is not scalable solution.  You have to change the design of table to be scalable.  This is temporary solution only.  You can refer @gordon-linoff recommendation below.

Answer (score 4):

SQL doesn't work like that.  You don't want to store conditions as strings.

Instead, you want two separate tables:

`Users`:

```
UserId   FirstName   LastName
   1     Riswan      Parambath
   2     Reda        Dridi
```

`UserLocations`:

```
UserLocationId   UserId   LocationId
      1             1        251
      2             2        733
      3             2        758
      4             2        783
```

The latter table is called a *junction* table (or sometimes an *association* table).  Your queries will be much faster and easier to construct.

Comment: As a side note, you (possibly) don't need the column `[UserLocationID]`. If a User can only ever be assigned to a Location once (although multiple different ones) then `[UserID]` and `[LocationID]` create a composite `PRIMARY KEY`, and the table is only ever going to be referenced if you require both fields anyway. If, however, a User could be related to the same Location twice, then yes, you need a separate ID column

Comment: @Lamu . . . I put id (as well as `createdby` and `createdat`) columns in pretty much all tables I create.  They are there for other purposes, such as keeping track of the order of insertion, providing a key for future foreign keys, and maintaining the table.

Comment: Fair play. Was only a point of observation (hence me saying possibly), nothing more. P.s. `rn` not `m`. ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your feedback. As i mentioned i am newbie to SQL I really don't have any clue how i can separate this table as you mentioned.

Comment: Reviewing down votes, I noticed I down voted this in error and I cannot undo it because of SO's time limit on changing votes (unless it is edited). My apologies, +1 in spirit!